# Put several .js files under a scope

Tags: javascript

I have a few large js files which functions and objects are living in the global scope and have function calls between them. Is there a relatively easy way to put them under local scope.

```
<script src="fileA.js"></script>
<script src="fileB.js"></script>
<script src="fileC.js"></script>
```

I've tried putting `(function(){` at the beginning of the A file and  `})();` at the end of the last one but it doesn't work.

10x for your kind help BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't.

The closest you could come is to set them up to share variables through a namespace (a single, global variable with a name selected to make collisions unlikely) such as `window.YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME = {}`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot wrap it like that, because each script is still parsed separately (the `<script>` tag does not work by just including the contents into the file).

You can simply manually concatenate the files, put `function(){ ... }()` around the entire contents, and use this newly concatenated script as a single unit.

If a rewrite of the script contents is viable, you can make them use a shared scope given to them in the factory method like Quentin mentioned in the other answer. However, an even better solution (if you can rewrite and if this is a bigger project) would be to switch to a full module concept with dependencies, like [AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html).

Comment: 10x for your ideas they are helpful. I already had that solution in mind as far as AMD it's really large project and it just won't work for that case. Appreciate your kind help

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using script src="fileA.js", you can get the content of fileA.js as string using Ajax. Than eval to your local scope.

```
eval.call(yourlocalscope, string)
```

Comment: While this works, it's a lot of additional complexity if the files depend on one another and have to be executed in order. It also causes debugging to be harder (unless you give a name to the evaluated string using some magic `//@source` comments that only some browsers support). If you want to load asynchronously anyway, it's better to switch to require.js or something else which has all those things handled.

Comment: Thanks it's a helpful solution +1 in my case I was looking for something relatively painless and easy for me.